# Can the sortable_table plugin do order by multiple columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the [sortable_table plugin](https://github.com/thoughtbot/sortable_table.git) for sorting an HTML table in a Rails app.

If we want to order by multiple columns, can sortable_table plugin do it
?
Example:

```
    select distinct brands.title as brands, models.title as model 
    from brands, models
    where 
    brands.id = models.brand_id
    order by brands.title desc, models.title desc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh.. I get it!

Just put sortable_attributes on controller as array.

For example:

```
sortable_attributes :brand_model => ["brands.title", "models.title"]
```